# Posted answer did not use logged in user id

Tags: support, user-accounts, display-names

I was logged into Quantitative Finance (beta).  I posted an answer to a [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/12892/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-calculate-the-internal-rate-of-return-irr).  The system created a new user id, rather than the one that I was logged in with.  Any idea what I did wrong? The id generated was user801.

Comment: Hmm, that looks weird indeed. But don't worry; this is just your display name; unlike on many other sites that's not identical to the user Id here. You can easily edit it back to "Bill". But please don't do that just yet while I try to find out how this happened.

Comment: Hmm, are you really sure that your display name on quant.se was ever "Bill"?

Comment: I thought my user id was 644204.  But just to post this question, I seem to have a separate, but somehow linked id of 263195.

Comment: Okay, I see the misunderstanding. Will write an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your user id is different on every site. On Stack Overflow, your user id is 644204, here on Meta Stack Exchange it's 263195, on Home Improvement it's 19940, and on Quantitative Finance it's 801. This is the number that appears in your profile link, e.g. https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/19940/bill.

Unlike many other websites, Stack Exchange makes a distinction between the user id and the user name (or display name, as it's called), which is why it's not a problem to have a [common name such as "Bill"](https://stackoverflow.com/users?search=bill). The name is only what's displayed, but it's not used to uniquely identify you.

If you don't set a display name when you create a new account on a site, the system assigns you the name "user12345", where 12345 is your user id. That's just so that there is *something* to display on your questions, answers, etc. You can then change that name to (almost) whatever you want (and these days we nudge new users to do exactly that as the first thing after they've created an account).

Now, if you already have a user account on one Stack Exchange site and you've set your display name there, and then you create a user account on a different site, we automatically use the same display name for that new account. However, when you created your account on Quantitative Finance back in 2011, you had not yet set your display name on Stack Overflow yet. In fact you set your display name to "Bill" on Stack Overflow about five minutes *after* you had created your Quant account, but you changed it only on Stack Overflow, and not network wide.

I am not sure anymore what that editing user interface looked like in 2011, but the "edit profile on one site" vs. "edit profile network-wide" distinction has traditionally been confusing people, and does so to this day. We currently have a project in the works that tries to make this much better.

A final thing to mention is that while your user id is different on each site, we still know you're the same person everywhere. We know that because you used the same login when you created the user accounts, and so all your accounts on the different Stack Exchange sites are connected to the same single "network account". That's the "network profile" link you see on the top right of all your profiles, and note that they all go to https://stackexchange.com/users/323911/bill.

---

I hope I've cleared up some of the confusion. All you really have to do is change your display name on Quantitative Finance to "Bill" by clicking the "edit" link in your profile there. And when you make changes to your display name or other parts of your profile, just click "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts" and the change will be visible on all sites that you have an account on. Again, with the new profile editing that's in the works, this should become much easier and more intuitive soon.

Comment: Thank you for the research and detailed answer.  It just wasn't immediately obvious that each site has separate accounts.